# Bootstrap Dropdown menu selected item not loading

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

linked bootstrap.min.css, bootstrap-theme.min.css, jquery.min.js",    bootstrap.js,dropdown.js

http://jsfiddle.net/id10922606/54edxsmv/1/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
});
</script>

<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Action</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-   toggle="dropdown"  aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Why selected item not loading instead of 'Action' list value. only working dropdown menu ? please help

Comment: Can you please update your code in fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure your fiddle includes the links / references to external resources.

When you say "Why selected item not loading instead of 'Action' list value", do you mean it's not updating the dropdown with the item you click on?  If so, you want to add the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();

    $('.dropdown-menu li a').click(function() {
        $('.btn:first-child').text($(this).text());
        $('.btn:first-child').val($(this).text());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/54edxsmv/4/

What this does, is when you click on an `li a` tag within the `.dropdown-menu` list, it will update the text and value of the first button `.btn:first-child` with the clicked items text.

There are many ways of handling multiple dropdowns, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();

    $.each($('.btn-group'), function() {

        var $dropdown = $(this);

        $dropdown.find('.dropdown-menu li a').click(function() {
            $dropdown.find('.btn:first-child').text($(this).text());
            $dropdown.find('.btn:first-child').val($(this).text());
        });
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/54edxsmv/5/

Comment: This is working fine. but its for single dropdown. when I am using multiple dropdowns this code working for all dropdowns together. what is the code for individual dropdown menus?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include code for multiple dropdowns